# Error #2032 while loading "http://web.archive.org" through URLLoader

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flexbuilder

Here is my code in AS3 ...

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://stackoverflow.com");
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

loader.load(request);
```

...
...

Error Detail :
Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032

Comment: You should modify the question to include more details.  IS that a compile time error or a run time error?  Are you running in an AIR app or in the browser?  You can't load archive.org files in the browser b/c there is no crossdomain.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

**One issue you have is that there isn't a onLoaded function created** - at least in your documentation above. I also noticed that you had an * in the url. I replaced that with one of the links 20080703183923 which returns a HTML page in flash to use. Here is the code to grab the info in flash ->

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://web.archive.org/web/20080703183923/http://stackoverflow.com");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
loader.load(request);

function onLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    trace(event.target.data);
    /************************************************************\ 
        returns the HTML printed out in the Flash Output. 
        You could then do whatever it is you want with it.
    \************************************************************/
}
```

Comment: The asterisk is perfectly fine in the url - it just returns a different page.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend downloading [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and using that to determine what the server response was.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem.  Here is what I found:

1. Error 2032 is a Stream Error, which means the file could not be loaded.
2. You should add always add an event handler to catch IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR. You could use [`error.getStackTrace()`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Error.html#getStackTrace%28%29) or [`error.message`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Error.html#message) to find out more about why the error occured.
3. You cannot download any resources from web.archive.org, because it doesn't seem to serve a crossdomain.xml policy file.  Security in Flash prevents you from downloading a URL from a remote server which does not explicitly allow your domain to access it.  This is probably the reason for your page request to fail.